# Why doesn't the area 51 site have a link to the subsequently launched site?

Tags: support, area-51

Here is an example of a [successful area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). Now computer science has been so successful on area 51 that there are about 3 computer science stack exchange sites. Its not possible for me to simply Google which site arose from this area 51 site.

To me - the obvious thing would be to click on the ***Launched*** link and have it take me to the site.

My question is: **Why doesn't the area 51 site have a link to the subsequently launched site?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But it does! Look below the list of stats, to the left of the rocket:

> ### [Visit the site now!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science/visit)

It's a redirect, so you wouldn't know from hovering over the link. I had trouble finding it at first too.

Comment: It's 'below the fold' - it might as well not be on the page.